# docker when starting two service why only shows one?

Tags: docker

I run this command:

```
docker run nginx -it
```

and again, so I started it two times but when I enter docker ps I got only one. Why?

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS     NAMES
a121e243159a   nginx     "/docker-entrypoint.…"   11 minutes ago   Up 11 minutes   80/tcp    adoring_golick
```

when I press docker ps -a then it shows all but why it shows not on only docker ps ? I mean I started it and its running

Comment: Please edit your post and add the output from `docker ps -a` to it

Comment: Such a scenario usually points to a container exiting due to an error or completion of a task. as pointed out by Hans please post the relevant output.

Comment: If you are not running it with the `-d` flag how are you running the second docker container? if you are using `CTRL+C` then your docker container will be terminated